# VS is giving me another solution to my constructor but I want to know why mine wont work

Tags: c++, constructor

My constructor has a green line underneath it saying "function definition not found".

Visual Studio has given me a fix, but I want to know why mine doesn't work.

```
#pragma once
#include "class_dayType.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    dayType day;
    string d;

    cout << "Enter day of week: ";
    cin >> d;

    day.set_day(d);
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class dayType {
public:
    string day;
    dayType();  //constructor with green line

    void set_day(string day_of_week) {
        string day = day_of_week;
    }
};
```

Visual Studio created this in another file and it worked. What is the difference between this and my constructor?

```
dayType::dayType()
{
}
```

Errors:

> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall dayType::dayType(void)" (??0dayType@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main    Day_of_Week
>
> LNK1120   1 unresolved externals  Day_of_Week

Comment: You dont seem to have one

Comment: read about declaration vs definition. The duplicate is more general, but the accepted answer covers also function declaration vs function definition

Answer (score 1):

```
dayType();
```

This is not a definition, it's just a declaration. It indicates that a constructor (or any function) will be present somewhere in the code later on.

You would need

```
dayType() 
{
}
```

Read more [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration-in-Cplusplus) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration).